# How to sort an array based on the numeric order of another array?

Tags: c, sorting, qsort

EDIT : This is all done in C.

Let's say I have the two following arrays :

```
int numFields[] = {5, 1, 3, 2, 7}
char charFields[] = {'a' , 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'}
```

I want to sort numFields numerically and have charFields resorted to match the new order of numFields such that :

```
int numFields[] = {1, 2, 3, 5, 7}
char charFields[] = {'b', 'd', 'c', 'a', 'e'}
```

I know that is possible to use qsort to sort numFields numerically, but is it possible to sort charFields to match the index changes of numFields? Is there a built in function or do I have to make my own implementation?

Thanks

Comment: @MarounMaroun what, and re-write the whole C project in Java?

Comment: Not directly - you would need to sort an index and then use that index to re-order the the original arrays.

Comment: Sort an array of indices from 0 to n-1 using the numFields array in the comparator and then reorder the charFields based on the indices.

Comment: The quicksort algorithm is very simple to implement. Obviously, the implemented version of the C standard library is not going to let you track the changed indexes, so, I recommend you to implement your own sort algorith to deal with it.

Comment: One approach would be to write your own implementation. which compares only `numFields` but swaps both `numFields` and `charFields` items. The other one would be rebuilding data to the array of structs `{ int num; char ch;}`, then compare only `num` filed of struct. Thera are more...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`qsort` lets you specify your own compare function to specify on what criteria the array should be sorted. It lets you sort an array of any type (can be `int`, can be `struct`) as long as you know the size of the objects you're sorting. Your best bet will be to create a `struct pair { int numValue; char charValue }` to represent the pair. You can

1. write a function to accept `numFields` and `charFields` and return an array of `pair`.
2. write a compare function, [using this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806541/struct-sorting-a-c-string-with-qsort#1806556) for reference. Other [code examples here](http://anyexample.com/programming/c/qsort__sorting_array_of_strings__integers_and_structs.xml).
3. call `qsort` on your array of pairs and your comparison function
4. write a function to transform the array of `pair`s back to `charFields`.

Answer (score 0):

simply declare a struct array with each element holding the number as well as the letter corresponding to it. Then sort the array according to the numbers

or use `qsort` with a specific call back function to do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int numFields[] = {5, 1, 3, 2, 7};
char charFields[] = {'a' , 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
// temporary arrays for sorted result   
int numFields2[5];
int charFields2[5];
// an index for sorting
int idx[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
// A cmompare function compares the numFields using the index values
int compar(const void* a,const void* b){
     return numFields[*(int*)a]-numFields[*(int*)b];
}

int main(void) {
    // sort the index values using the comapare function
    qsort(idx, 5, sizeof(int), compar);
    // use the sorted index to copy the values in the new sort order
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
      numFields2[i] = numFields[idx[i]];
      charFields2[i] = charFields[idx[i]];
     }
     // Copy result to original arrays
     for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        numFields[i] = numFields2[i];
        charFields[i] = charFields2[i];
     }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here i try to devlop bubble sort program try using it.,

```
int temp;
char a;
for(i=0;i<no;i++)
    {
        for(j=i;j<no;j++)
        {
            if(numFields[i] > numFields[j])
            {
                temp=numFields[i];
                numFields[i]=numFields[j];
                numFields[j]=temp;


                a=charFields[i];
                charFields[i]=charFields[j];
                charFields[j]=a;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: why not?? using this he can make his own implementation.

Comment: -1: bubble sort is very inefficient - also the code above is buggy.

Comment: ya that’s why I specify ..i know bubble sort is not proper .

Comment: he want own implementation code that's why i give this type of answer

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but it's a very bad idea to re-implement sorting algorithms unless you really need to. Even in the simplest implementation it's easy to introduce bugs.

Comment: @Joe: +1 - and if you really do need to re-implement a sort routine then bubble sort would be a very bad choice.